# How to force re-render whole application regardless of state?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to re-render whole app regardless whether state changes or not? Sort of like `this.forceUpdate()` but on global App level instead of just one component?

Comment: I guess you can do this with https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate . But can you please share the use case? I have worked on several projects but never encountered such a scenario

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja  I do aware of `this.forceUpdate` as stated in my question, however I think it only re-render the particular component and not on app level. One of the most common use case would be supporting multi languages. The moment we change a language, state doesnt change however a re-render is required

Comment: got it.. for multi language support you can check https://github.com/gitpoint/git-point .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to restart your app regardless state change/update. this library can help in React Native

https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart

from documentation:

```
yarn add react-native-restart
//link manually or
react-native link react-native-restart

import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';

//Immediately reload the React Native Bundle
RNRestart.Restart();
```